# Pandas python barplot by subgroup

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Ok so I have a dataframe object that's indexed as follows:

```
index,       rev,      metric1   (more metrics.....)

exp1,       92365,     0.018987  
exp2,       92365,    -0.070901  
exp3,       92365,     0.150140  
exp1,       87654,     0.003008  
exp2,       87654,    -0.065196   
exp3,       87654,    -0.174096
```

For each of these metrics I want to create individual stacked barplots comparing them based on their rev.

here's what I've tried:

```
df = df[['rev', 'metric1']]   
df = df.groupby("rev")  
df.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

This results in 2 individual bar graphs of the metric.  Ideally I would have these two merged and stacked (right now stacked=true does nothing).  Any help would be much appreciated.

This would give me my ideal result, however I don't think reorganizing to fit this is the best way to achieve my goal as I have many metrics and many revisions.

```
index,   metric1(rev87654), metric1(rev92365)
exp1,    0.018987,          0.003008 
exp2,   -0.070901,         -0.065196
exp3,    0.150140,         -0.174096
```

This is my goal.  (made by hand)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GRqB.png

Comment: What do you mean by "merged"? If you want a sum or average or whatnot, you need to do that to your groupby object first

Comment: I added a comment to my main post.  I want a graph that has my experiments on the x axis, however I want each metric to be subdivided by the rev number if that makes sense.  I'll add graphs shortly.

Answer (score 0):

following from this matplotlib gallery example:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

there they get multiple to plot by calling bar once for each set.

You could access these values in pandas with indexing operations as follows:

```
fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(16.2,10),dpi=300)
Y = Tire2[Tire2.SL==Tire2.SL.unique()[0]].SA.values[0:13]
X = linspace(0,size(Y),size(Y))

ax.bar(X,Y,width=.4)
Y = Tire2[Tire2.SL==Tire2.SL.unique()[2]].SA.values[0:13]
X = linspace(0,size(Y),size(Y))+.5
ax.bar(X,Y,width=.4,color='r')
```

working from the inside out:

1. get all of the unique values of 'SL' in one of the cols (rev in your case)
2. Get a Boolean vector of all rows where 'SL' equals the first (or nth) unique value
3. Index Tire by that Boolean vector (this will pull out only those rows where the vector is `True`
4. access the values of `SA` or a metric in yourcase. (took only the `[0:13]' values because i was testing this on a huge data set)
5. bar plot those values

if your experiments are consistently in order in the frame(as shown), that's that.  Otherwise you might need to run a little sorting to get your Y values in the right order. `.sort(column name)` should take care of that. In my code, i'd slip it in between `...[0]]` and`.SA...`

In general, this kind of operation can really help you out in wrangling big frames.  `.between` is useful.  And you can always add, multiply etc. the Boolean vectors to construct more complex logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get the plot you want automatically without doing exactly the reorganization you specify at the end.  The answer by user3823992 gives you more detailed control of the plots, but if you want them more automatic here is some temporary reorganization that should work using the indexing similarly but also concatenating back into a DataFrame that will do the plot for you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

exp = ['exp1','exp2','exp3']*2
rev = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
met1 = np.linspace(-0.5,1,6)
met2 = np.linspace(1.0,5.0,6)
met3 = np.linspace(-1,1,6)
df = pd.DataFrame({'rev':rev, 'met1':met1, 'met2':met2, 'met3':met3}, index=exp)

for met in df.columns:
    if met != 'rev':
        merged = df[df['rev'] == df.rev.unique()[0]][met]
        merged.name = merged.name+'rev'+str(df.rev.unique()[0])
        for rev in df.rev.unique()[1:]:
            tmp = df[df['rev'] == rev][met]
            tmp.name = tmp.name+'rev'+str(rev)
            merged = pd.concat([merged, tmp], axis=1)

        merged.plot(kind='bar')
```

This should give you three plots, one for each of my fake metrics.

**EDIT :** Or something like this might do also

```
df['exp'] = df.index
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, values='met1', rows=['exp'], cols=['rev'])
pt.plot(kind='bar')
```